# jagged csv serde for hive

Tags: hive, hive-serde

Is there a way to define a Hive table with jagged header files. keep nulls for missing columns?
I have tsv files with different header lines. i.e.:

```
Name  Age  Height
Chris 48   5'10"
Jim   25   5'11"
```

then another file

```
Name Group Age Height
Bill Acct  32  5'5"
Amy  Bllg  35  5'6"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no solution to do it directly. You need to do in two steps:

1. Load file X into temporary table.
2. Insert values from temporary table into final table.

Same question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39580335/how-to-load-data-to-same-hive-table-if-file-has-different-number-of-columns).

Comment: thank you, i think if i'm doing 2 steps then I can probably also just transform the data through another process into single line jsons